# Tycoon script for TI-84 Calculator

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

I made a Tycoon script for TI-84 Plus CE and I don't think it's really good.
I'm not that good at calculator programming and I don't know much. I just learned some from a friend and a couple YouTube videos.

I was wondering, does anyone know how I can improve this script to make it better?

Here's what I have:

Btw the `->` is the STO key.

```
:ClrHome
:13->S
:5->T
:13->X
:5->Y
:0->B
:5->C
:1->D
:Output(T,S,"CASH:"
:Output(Y,X,"M"
:getkey->A
:X->S
:Y->T
:If A=26
:Then
:X+1->X
:If X=27
:26->x
:End
:If A=34
:Then
:Y+1->Y
:If Y=11
:10->Y
:End
:If A=25
:Then
:Y-1->Y
:If Y=1
:2->Y
:End
:If A=11
:Then
:Stop
:End
:If X=D and Y=C
:Then
:B+1->B
:Output(1,6,B
:End
:If B≥200
:Then
:6->E
:1->F
:Output(E,F,"5"
:End
:If X=F and Y=E and B≥200
:Then
:B+5->B
:Output(1,6,B
:End
:If B≥1500
:Then
:7->G
:1->H
:Output(G,H,"10"
:End
:If X=H and Y=G and B≥1500
:Then
:B+10->B
:Output(1,6,B
:End
:End
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might better belong to codereview.stackexchange.com (assuming it is working correctly), in case not, it should be stated what needs to be improved, what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Future questions of this nature should be asked at codereview.SE, but I'll take a look at some optimizations for you anyway.

I will only be looking for optimizations in size, not speed (although they may make your program faster). **Here are some:**

- First off, four of these lines can have their end quotes removed (-4)
- `0->B:5->C` can be `DelVar B5->C` (you can remove the following colon) (-1)
- You don't need a `Then` or `End` with your If statement if the condition is one line. So, `:If A=11:Then:Stop:End` can just be `:If A=11:Stop` (-4)

Now for the major optimizations I see:

**First,** and perhaps more obvious, is the fact that you call `:Output(1,6,B` a lot. It looks like you can just move this outside your `If` block, and remove the `Then` and `End` for -4 bytes each

**Second,** which you may not have known about, are the `min(` and `max(` commands, which return the smaller or larger of two values or of a list, respectively. Here's an example:

```
:If A=26
:Then
:X+1->X
:If X=27
:26->X
:End
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```
:If A=26
:min(26,X+1->X
```

It looks like you can use this optimization four times, which is significant because it makes the program smaller, faster, and more readable.

**Overall,** I hope I was able to help you. If you have any questions at all, please ask :)

Comment: while that optimization did help me, the point of the question was if there was a way to make the actual tycoon any better with the function of the tycoon.

Comment: Well see, I am being objective in my answer -- you are requesting something more subjective (i.e. what is better?). Since you haven't told me what is "better" (other than faster/smaller which I addressed), I can't do any more but guess. And, if you have those ideas you can always try them yourself too :) glad I could help somewhat